# How do I make an Access Report show only the data for one selection

Tags: ms-access

I have created a simple Report in Access based off of a click event from a button after selecting a Part Number in a listbox.

When I select only one part number in the listbox and click the button the report opens just fine. However it displays all of the data from my table and not just the data for that ONE part number that was selected.

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query to call the information and set it up the way you want it then in the SQL view where you see SELECT put TOP 1. Then base your report off of that query.

Comment: Thank you for your response!